# Is it ok to load configuration xml every time in a batch script?

Tags: java, xml, batch-file

I have a every minute scheduler in java. It will load the configuration from a xml and do sftp.

```
<config>
   <server>
      <meta>
         <ipaddress>192.1.6.4</ipaddress>
         <username>userid</username>
         <scriptname>script.sh</scriptname>
      </meta>
      <files>
         <file name="" startswith="rajesh_" endswith=".xml" desc="" path="/path/" />
      </files>
   </server>
</config>
```

If the number of server increases, (may be 100 server with 200 files each) is it feasible to load the configuration on every minute? I am currently running from crontab for every minute.

If i run as a single java process for long time will it be more efficient?

Comment: I don't quite understand how the config file is saved, but couldn't you check for date modified/compare last known filesize, etc.

Comment: I am reading the config file and saving it as some java objects

Comment: So you could compare the date modified on the file to check if you need to actually load the file at all.

Comment: @Mathemats I am not saving anything in the DB. Once the job done, the process will exit. So I need to read xml every time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only correct answer to this question is: measure it.
Do a test to see if the performance is acceptable.

Running a single java process for a long time *could* be more efficient, but it could very well be less efficient. Without any knowledge about your application, it's impossible to tell.

So here's my suggestion:
- Make an educated guess about the expected number of servers/files
- Perform a test with that number
- Decide whether the performance is acceptable or not.